# javac cant be found even after add enviromental var

Tags: java, windows, jvm, javac

Good morning :)

I have a problem with install and using JDK. I have read a tone of tutorials and how to fix it but nothing helped me out yet. 
So I have installed JDK 64bit. into

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31

I'm sure it is 64bit version. Then I have install Android Studio. Installation goes smooth. When I launch, it says that it cant find JVM and I need to add environment variable JAVA_HOME with path into it. Which I did. But error still is showing up. So I checked `javac -version`in windows console and get cannot find such command error. I have chcecked my `Path` variable and add into it

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\

But that aren't help neither. I'm lack of ideas right now :(

My user variable:

> JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\

My system Path variable:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
```

Comment: Did you restart your terminal after changing the `Path` from GUI ? I advice you to use `JAVA_HOME` in your path, that's more maintainable :) (`%JAVA_HOME%\bin`)

Comment: is your jdk version that you installed compatible with 64 bit os and try java -version and not javac -version

Comment: @vikeng21: If the goal is to use the JDK, then checking `javac -version` makes sense. `java -version` would be satisfied with just a JRE.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder thanks for pointing out the difference

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Call `cmd` (Run as administrator). Enter command: `javac -version`
[image]

**2.** I hope after you restart computer, You will don't need `Run as administrator`.

**3.** If above tip can't success, give other tip a chance to try: Type full path manually.

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin"\javac -version`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So the case was restarting windows. I dont know why it was essential on Windows 8 while not necessary on Windows 7 but that was the case. Thanks @Nizil for help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a problem with the Android Studio studio.bat file 
and here it is

```
    ::------------------------------------------------------
    :: Locate a JDK installation directory which will be used to run the IDE.
    :: Try (in order): ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK, ..\jre, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME.
    :: ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    IF EXIST "%ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK%" SET JDK=%ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK%
    IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
    IF EXIST "%~dp0\..\jre" SET JDK=%~dp0\..\jre
    IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
    IF EXIST "%JDK_HOME%" SET JDK=%JDK_HOME%
    IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
    IF EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%" SET JDK=%JAVA_HOME%
    IF "%JDK%" == "" GOTO error
```

Do you get the problem in the last 2 lines of code?
It seems that if your environmental variable is %JAVA_HOME% the batch file will GOTO error and an error message will be displayed and that's it NO ANDROID STUDIO FOR YOU, even though %JAVA_HOME% contains a valid path but if the environmental variable is something like %ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK% like mine is because I created it myself then it will work

---

#### PROPOSED SOLUTIONS

(1) Edit the batch file
Where you see this
`IF EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%" SET JDK=%JAVA_HOME%
IF "%JDK%" == "" GOTO error` 
Change it to this
`IF EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%" SET JDK=%JAVA_HOME%
IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
IF "%JDK%" == "" GOTO error` 
(2) Create an environmental variable named %ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK%
as shown here
https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500